# How to export and preserve linked Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, html, markdown, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have multiple Jupyter notebooks that are linked to one another such that **Notebook1.ipydb** contains a link to **Notebook2.ipydb** with the markdown `[Notebook2](Notebook2.ipynb)` and vice versa.

When exporting all notebooks to HTML via `nbconvert`, the link to **Notebook2.ipynb** is preserved. I would like to change that link to the exported **Notebook2.html** so the linked HTML files function as a static website.

I tried to detect if I was running in iPython using `get_ipython().__class__.__name__`, but it executes this code *before* converting to HTML.

Is there a way to detect a static file to conditionally render the right markdown? Is there another way to preserve linked notebooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only really two options. One is to link to `Notebook2.html` in the first place and the other is to create a custom preprocessor for `nbconvert`.

```
from nbconvert.preprocessors import Preprocessor
import re


class CustomPreprocessor(Preprocessor):

    def preprocess_cell(self, cell, resources, index):

        if 'source' in cell and cell.cell_type == "markdown":
            cell.source = re.sub(r"\[(.*)\]\(\1\.ipynb\)",r"[\1](\1.html)",cell.source)

        return cell, resources
```

Save this to a file, then add to your nbconvert config file (located at `~/.jupyter/jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` or can be generated using the command `jupyter nbconvert --generate-config`) the line:

`c.HTMLExporter.preprocessors = ['CustomPreprocessor.CustomPreprocessor']`

This assumes that the custom preprocessor file is named CustomPreprocessor and is located in the same directory as the files you're trying to convert. You could also properly install it as a module too.

Comment: Nice solution. I used `r"\[([^]]*)\]\(([^)]*)\.ipynb\)"` for the regular expression and `r"[\1](\2.html)"` for the replacement text. This way the link text doesn't have to match the first part of the file name.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell that regex is indeed better because it's more general. Glad you liked my answer :)

Comment: Cool stuff, also worked for me. I already had a `nbconvert.HTMLExporter` instance, which I appended the preprocessor to using [register_preprocessor](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.nbconvert.exporters.exporter.html#IPython.nbconvert.exporters.exporter.Exporter.register_preprocessor). This way I didn't need to touch the config.