# Different markdown output depending on target in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to produce different output from markdown depending on whether the web app is being used or the target is HTML?

I'd like to display one thing when Jupyter Notebook is being used and another when the page is being viewed as HTML.  A typical example is links.  When the user is viewing a notebook using Jupyter Notebook, it makes sense to link to other notebooks.  But when the notebook is converted to HTML using nbconvert, it makes sense to link to the corresponding HTML page.  So I'd like something like this

```
{if target=="html"} [Next](foo.html) {else} [Next](foo.ipynb) {end if}
```

Is there a way to do this or a sensible way to get a similar effect?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255564/how-to-export-and-preserve-linked-jupyter-notebooks/42279992#42279992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the markdown that Jupyter uses supports conditionals, but if you can assume that the path to the `.ipynb` file is the same as the path to the `.html` file you could always create a custom preprocessor for Nbconvert that replaces the `.ipynb` extension with `.html`

See [my answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42279992/7458681) for more details.